# sumiu uma linha do meu vetor de objetos

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando rodar esse algoritmo js de forma a exercitar o que aprendi, a ideia era multiplicar as idades por 2 e então criar um filtro que retirassem os usuários com idade menos que 50, porém o algoritmo `find` que deveria percorrer todo o vetor executa somente a primeira iteração que a condição é aceita, não sei qual o erro do algoritmo

```
//script

const usuarios = [
    {nome: 'diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'facebook'}
];



usuarios.map(function(item){ item.idade *= 2});

const novosUsers = usuarios.find(item => item.idade <= 50);

console.log(novosUsers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Não está sumindo nenhum item do seu vetor, acontece que você utilizou o método `find`, que retorna o **primeiro** item que atende a sua condição:

```js
const usuarios = [
    {nome: 'diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'facebook'}
];

usuarios.map(function(item){ item.idade *= 2});

const novosUsers = usuarios.find(item => item.idade <= 50);

console.log(novosUsers);
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

---

Caso você queira retornar todos os itens de seu vetor que atendam a sua condição, você deve utilizar o método `filter`:

```js
const usuarios = [
    {nome: 'diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
    {nome: 'lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'facebook'}
];

usuarios.map(function(item){ item.idade *= 2});

const novosUsers = usuarios.filter(item => item.idade <= 50);

console.log(novosUsers);
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Comment: Obrigado, erro de atençao meu.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade a função "map" não modifica a lista, ela retorna outra lista modificada. Além disso, você está usando o método "find" ao invés de "filter" para filtrar os elementos. Segue, abaixo, uma versão modificada do seu código que talvez seja o que você procura:

```
const usuarios = [
{nome: 'diego', idade: 23, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
{nome: 'gabriel', idade: 15, empresa: 'rocketseat'},
{nome: 'lucas', idade: 30, empresa: 'facebook'}
];

let usuariosComIdadeDuplicada = usuarios.map(function(item){ return {...item, idade:  item.idade * 2}; });

const novosUsers = usuariosComIdadeDuplicada.filter(item => item.idade <= 50);

console.log(novosUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

O algoritmo ta funcionando de maneira correta.
O [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ele percorre o array e retorna o primeiro elemento que tiver `true` como resultado da callback.
Para retornar todos que passem na condição, você de usar o [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro). Esse sim vai percorrer e retornar um novo array com os elementos que passaram na condição da callback.

Comment: valeu, eu n tinha notado que usei a função errada.